# Allowing microphone access(permission) in WebView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, webview

send audio is not working can you please help
I would appreciate if you show me where to write the codes.
send audio is not working can you please help
I would appreciate if you show me where to write the codes.
send audio is not working can you please help
I would appreciate if you show me where to write the codes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView web;
String webUrl = "https://tuk.az";

public Context context;

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

// the same for Android 5.0 methods only
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myweb);
    web.loadUrl(webUrl);
    WebSettings mywebsettings = web.getSettings();
    mywebsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // improve webview performance

    web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    web.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mywebsettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mywebsettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    mywebsettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mywebsettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    mywebsettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mywebsettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
   // mywebsettings.setSavePassword(true);
   // mywebsettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

        // for Lollipop, all in one
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                // create the file where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // continue only if the file was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            return true;
        }

        // creating image files (Lollipop only)
        private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // create an image file name
            imageStorageDir = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            return imageStorageDir;
        }

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try {
                File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "DirectoryNameHere");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); // save to the private variable

                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                // captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.image_chooser));
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // openFileChooser for other Android versions
        /* may not work on KitKat due to lack of implementation of openFileChooser() or onShowFileChooser()
           https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220
           however newer versions of KitKat fixed it on some devices */
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }
    });

    //download

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
        }
    }

    //handle download
    web.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLenght) {

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent",userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

// return here when file selected from camera or from SD Card
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // code for all versions except of Lollipop
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }

            Uri result = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }

    } // end of code for all versions except of Lollipop

    // start of code for Lollipop only
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null || data.getData() == null) {
                // if there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    } // end of code for Lollipop only
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(web.canGoBack()){`enter code here`
        web.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permission in the manifest? You can do that by implementing this code:

```
<manifest ... >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"/>
...

</manifest>
```